# R: How to change the type of object in the list?

Tags: r

In the R language, a list can contain everything, even a list, but how to change the type of object inside a list? 
e.g. How to transform the first column of a list from "list" into "integer"?

```
# my own data
test1 <- read_csv("E:/ProgramData/R/Food/Food3.csv", col_types = cols(Subject = col_integer()))

typeof(test1)
typeof(test1[,1])
class(test1[,1])

# the datasets data
test2 <- datasets::Theoph

typeof(test2)
typeof(test2[,1])
class(test2[,1])

[1] "list"
[1] "list"
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
[1] "list"
[1] "integer"
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

"test1" is read from an arbitrary csv file. It's a list but the first column is "tbl". While "test2" is the default datasets, it's also a list but the first column is "integer".

I want to know how to transfer the test1's type into "integer" like "test2"

Comment: We need a reproducible example of the list you're trying to change.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).